# MVC Joomla 1.5 - Save

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

in my MVC somehow it does not jump into the save function of the controller??? I tried to do some die(); exit points but this does not help. The main problem is the save function. But as well the delete does not work as well.

This is the CONTROLLER.

```
    <?php

//*********************************
//    Controller
//*********************************

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); 
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class FindmeControllerStylelink extends JController
{


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    echo '<br>Controller: FindmeControllerStylelink';

}

function display()
{

    JRequest::setVar('view', 'stylelink');

    parent::display();


}

function edit()
{

    JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'stylelink' );
    JRequest::setVar(   'layout', 'form'  );

    parent::display();

}
function add(){

    JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'stylelink' );
    JRequest::setVar(   'layout', 'form'  );

    parent::display();

}



function delete(){

    $id = JRequest::getVar( 'id' );

    $model = $this->getModel('stylelink');

    if ($model->delete()) {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Data Deleted!' );
    } else {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Error Deleting Data' );
    }


    echo 'delete ';
    die();

    // Check the table in so it can be edited.... we are done with it anyway
    $link = 'index.php?option=com_findme&controller=stylelinks';
    $this->setRedirect($link, $msg);
}



function save()
{



    // Check for request forgeries
    JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

    $post   = JRequest::get('post');
    print_r($post);



    echo 'save ';
    die();

    $model = $this->getModel('stylelink');

    if ($model->store($post)) {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Stylelink Saved' );
    } else {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Error Saving Stylelink' );
    }


    $link = 'index.php?option=com_findme&controller=stylelinks';
    $this->setRedirect($link, $msg);
 }

 function cancel()
 {
    // Check for request forgeries
    JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

    echo 'save ';
    die();

    $link = 'index.php?option=com_findme&controller=stylelinks';
    $this->setRedirect($link, $msg);
 }

 }
 ?>
```

The VIEW.

```
<?php 

//*********************************
//  insurances  View
//*********************************

defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted Access' ); 
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view' ); 

class FindmeViewStylelink extends JView {

  function display($tpl = null) { 

    global $mainframe, $option, $view;

    echo '<br>View: FindmeViewStylelink';

    //$model =& $this->getModel();
    //$model    = &$this->getModel( 'stylelink' );
    //var_dump($model);

    $db     =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $uri    =& JFactory::getURI();
    $view   = JRequest::getWord( 'controller' );
    //echo '<br>controller '.$view;
    //echo '<br>option '.$option;


    // Get data from the model
    $item       = & $this->get( 'Data');
     print_r($item);


    $this->assignRef('user',JFactory::getUser());
    $this->assignRef('item',$item);



    // //new Method
    // $this->assignRef('user',JFactory::getUser());
    // $this->assignRef('items',$model->_log_items);
    // $this->assignRef('lists',$model->_log_lists);
    // $this->assignRef('pagination',$model->_log_pagination);

      parent::display($tpl);



 } 
} 
?>
```

This is the FORM.

```
<?php 

//*********************************
//  Stylelink
//*********************************

ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


JHTML::stylesheet('findme.css', 'components/com_findme/css/');


defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$viewname = 'stylelink';
JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip');

require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components/com_findme/includes/functions.php');

// Set toolbar items for the page
$edit       = JRequest::getVar('edit',true);
JToolBarHelper::title('Style Link' );
JToolBarHelper::save();
if (!$edit)  {
    JToolBarHelper::cancel();
} else {
    // for existing items the button is renamed `close`
    JToolBarHelper::cancel( 'cancel', 'Close' );
}


echo '<h1>Stylelink Verwaltung </h1>';

?>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitbutton(pressbutton) {
    var form = document.adminForm;
    if (pressbutton == 'cancel') {
        submitform( pressbutton );
        return;
    }

    // do field validation
    if (form.cat_id.value == ""){
        alert( "<?php echo JText::_( 'You must select a category', true ); ?>" );
    } else if (form.url_link.value == ""){
        alert( "<?php echo JText::_( 'You must have a url.', true ); ?>" );
    } else {
        submitform( pressbutton );
    }
}
</script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
<div class="col width-50">
    <fieldset class="adminform">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'Details' ); ?></legend>

        <table class="admintable">


            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="title">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'ID' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->item->id;?>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="title">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'Name' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text_area" type="text" name="title" id="title" size="100" 
maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $this->item->name;?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="cat_id">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'cat_id' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text_area" type="text" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" size="10" 
 maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $this->item->cat_id;?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="language">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'language' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text_area" type="text" name="language" id="language" size="10" 
 maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $this->item->language;?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="active">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'active' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text_area" type="text" name="active" id="active" size="2" 
 maxlength="2" value="<?php echo $this->item->active;?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="url_link">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'url_link' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea class="text_area" cols="60" rows="4" name="url_link" 
 id="url_link"><?php echo $this->item->url_link; ?></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="url_img_small">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'url_img_small' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea class="text_area" cols="60" rows="4" name="url_img_small" 
 id="url_img_small"><?php echo $this->item->url_img_small; ?></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                    <label for="url_img_big">
                        <?php echo JText::_( 'url_img_big' ); ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea class="text_area" cols="60" rows="4" name="url_img_big" 
 id="url_img_big"><?php echo $this->item->url_img_big; ?></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>






        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_findme" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="stylelinks" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
<?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
</form>
?>
```

Here is the MODEL

```
<?php


// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

class FindmeModelStylelink extends JModel
{

var $_id = null;
var $_data = null;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    echo '<br>FindmeModelStylelink ';

    $id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0);


    $edit   = JRequest::getVar('edit',true);

    if($edit)
        $this->setId((int)$id);
}


function setId($id)
{
    echo '<br/>id ',$id;
    // Set  id and wipe data
    $this->_id      = $id;
    $this->_data    = null;


}

function &getData()
{
    // Load the  data
    if ($this->_loadData())
    {
        // Initialize some variables
        $user = &JFactory::getUser();

    }
    else  $this->_initData();

    return $this->_data;
}

function store($data)
{
    $row =& $this->getTable();
    echo '<br/> store';

    // Bind the form fields to the style link table
    if (!$row->bind($data)) {
        $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }

    // Create the timestamp for the date
    $row->timestamp = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // if new item, order last in appropriate group
    //if (!$row->id) {
       // $where = 'catid = ' . (int) $row->catid ;
       // $row->ordering = $row->getNextOrder( $where );
    //}

    // Make sure the link table is valid
    if (!$row->check()) {
        $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }

    // Store the  link table to the database
    if (!$row->store()) {
        $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function delete($id = array())
{
    $result = false;

    if (count( $cid ))
    {
        JArrayHelper::toInteger($cid);
        $cids = implode( ',', $cid );
        $query = 'DELETE FROM #__findme_style_link'
            . ' WHERE id IN ( '.$cids.' )';
        $this->_db->setQuery( $query );
        if(!$this->_db->query()) {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function _loadData()
{
    // Lets load the content if it doesn't already exist
    if (empty($this->_data))
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * '
            . ' FROM #__findme_style_link AS a WHERE a.id = '.(int) $this->_id;

        echo 'query '.$query;

        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $this->_data = $this->_db->loadObject();
        return (boolean) $this->_data;
    }
    return true;
}


function _initData()
{
    // Lets load the content if it doesn't already exist
    if (empty($this->_data))
    {
        $stylelink = new stdClass();
        $stylelink->id              = 0;
        $stylelink->cat_id          = null;
        $stylelink->language        = null;
        $stylelink->name            = null;
        $stylelink->url_link        = null;
        $stylelink->url_img_small   = null;
        $stylelink->url_img_big     = null;
        $stylelink->active          = null;
        $stylelink->click_count     = 0;
        $this->_data = $stylelink;
        return (boolean) $this->_data;
    }
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: why are you developing a component for Joomla 1.5? It's old, unsupported and has security issues.

Comment: YES YES I know! but it is used only INTERNAL and we move to 3.1 soon